# Using LIKE to search in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have an SQL query as below.

```
select *
from table 
where content like '%' + search_content + '%'
```

If `search_content = 'JAVA'`, it will return data containing `xxxJAVAxxx` which is OK.

But if my `search_content = 'JAVA ABC XYZ'`, it is not returning data containing `xxxJAVAxxx`. Which is not a case I want.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: You have tagged 3 different database products, MySQL, SQL Server & SQLite - please remove those which are not relevant.

Comment: You have said what you do not want, but not what you do want.

Comment: If you are looking for any 1 of 3 phrases, you need to search for each of them separately.

Comment: if `search_content = 'JAVA ABC XYZ'` ofc it wont return data containing `xxxJAVAxxx`. it will literally become `where content like '%JAVA ABC XYZ%'`.. is `xxxJAVAxxx` equal to `JAVA ABC XYZ`? no.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags... feel free to as a single RDBMS tag back.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example you can add the *OR* condition to cover all cases: the content contains, starts or endswith the desired string.

```
select *
from table 
where (content like '%JAVA%' or content like 'JAVA%' or content like '%JAVA')
```

A more elegant way (assuming you using postgres)

```
select *
from table
where position('JAVA' in content) > 0
```

What it does? It finds the position where the 'JAVA' substring can be found in content. If the substring exists the positon is higher that 0.

You can find an equivalent functions in SQL Server.

```
select *
from table
where CHARINDEX('JAVA', content) > 0
```